# fixed header width 100%

Tags: html, css

i have the following code but for some reason does not work.

```
<body>
    <div class="body_wrapper">
        <header></header>
    </div>    
</body>
```

i would like body_wrapper to have margin:20px but when put position:fixed to header ignores it from the right side.

http://jsfiddle.net/vfe1bz65/

i want header take width 100% of the body_wrapper. i tried putting right:20px, right:20px but nothing

is this possible without putting for example width:98%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `width` and set both `left` and `right` properties
e.g.  http://jsfiddle.net/rbk7jv8b/

```
header {
    min-height:160px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Another approach is using `calc()` for the `width` property  (`100%` minus `40px` of margin)
e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/f1ay8zkr/

```
header {
    min-height:160px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: As this solves the problem, you didn't offer no explanation how `fixed` elements work. Also, I believe you can [drop the prefixes for calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Answer (score 0):

Your div  isn't close.

```
<body>
    <div class="body_wrapper">
        <header></header>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Then, use left and right properties :

```
header {
    min-height:160px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: typographical mistake sorry. look the jsfiddle its correct

Comment: Error in the jsfiddle too, but that's not the problem. Use left and right properties to replace margin/padding :)

Answer (score 0):

add `right:20px;` and `left:20px;` the remove `width:100%`

```
header {
  min-height: 160px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```